# Spacebar not being detected in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a 2d Minecraft clone using Python and Pygame. Everything works except one thing. When I press the spacebar, it is supposed to clear the screen by removing all positions from the "positions" variable. It is not working. I have put a "print("hello")" there and it didn't work. I do not know why it isn't working because it isn't coming up with any errors. I am fairly new to python and Stackoverflow, so help would be much appriciated. Here is the code.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((480,320))
pygame.display.set_caption(("Mini Minecraft"))
block = pygame.image.load("Stone.png")
background = pygame.image.load("Background.png")
running = True

positions = []

def roundToMultiple(n, m):
    return round(n / m) * m

while running:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()

        if event.type == pygame.K_SPACE:
            positions = []

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            posX, posY = event.pos  
            posXRound = roundToMultiple(posX, 32)
            posYRound = roundToMultiple(posY, 32)
            positions.append((posXRound, posYRound))
        
    mouseX, mouseY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    mouseXRound = roundToMultiple(mouseX, 32)
    mouseYRound = roundToMultiple(mouseY, 32)

    if mouseXRound > 448:
        mouseXRound = 448
    if mouseYRound > 288:
        mouseYRound = 288
    
    win.blit(background, (0,0))
    for pos in positions:
        win.blit(block, pos)
    win.blit(block, (mouseXRound, mouseYRound))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to check that the event type is a key press `pygame.KEY_DOWN` and then check if the event key is space `pygame.K_SPACE`

```
        if event.type == pygame.KEY_DOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                positions = []
```